# Check for specific header value in RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm configuring my new Apache2.4 web server.

Into one of my VirtualHost I configure a redirect for everybody to a maintenance page when I set the `<If>` condition to true, except if a custom request's header contains a value:

```
<If "true">
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UserId} !=ab123
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/maintenance.html
    RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.html [R=302]
</If>
```

Is it possible to allow the check of many values instead of only one?

I would like something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UserId} not in (ab123, ze678, gt456)
```

Which are admin's UserId.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to include any `IF` condition. The below should be fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UserId} !^(ab123|ze678|gt465)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.html [R=302]
```

The first two `RewriteCond` work in a logical `AND` so the rule won't be executed unless both are true. You can use an `OR`d regex to check the userids coming in your header.

And if the field contains other values, you can remove the anchors `^` and `$`, but then the check won't be as safe